# ServiceNamePrincipal to nslookup

Tags: powershell

```
# Source / credit:
# https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18996.active-directory-powershell-script-to-list-all-spns-used.aspx


cls
$search = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
$search.filter = "(servicePrincipalName=*)"

## You can use this to filter for OU's:
## $results = $search.Findall() | ?{ $_.path -like '*OU=whatever,DC=whatever,DC=whatever*' }
$results = $search.Findall()

foreach( $result in $results ) {
    $userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
    Write-host "Object Name = " $userEntry.name -backgroundcolor "yellow" -foregroundcolor "black"
    Write-host "DN      =      "  $userEntry.distinguishedName
    Write-host "Object Cat. = "  $userEntry.objectCategory
    Write-host "servicePrincipalNames"

    $i=1
    foreach( $SPN in $userEntry.servicePrincipalName ) {
        Write-host "SPN(" $i ")   =      " $SPN
        $i+=1
    }
    Write-host ""
}
nslookup $SPN
```

---

I would like to use nslookup on the service principal names.

Comment: What is the question? Is the script you posted not working? If so, what results are you expecting and what are you getting? If you're getting error messages, please post them in full :)

Comment: I want to run the script but to take each SPN with a domain name into nslookup. Basically to get the IP address of any servers, etc.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party but a thing to note is that the you are going to want to make the nslookup in the foreach loop, and strip the string to only include the URL.... This was the OSCP right? lol
Working on this myself, Dropping a full answer shortly ! I would hope, given the age of this post, that is has be solved on your end lol... I'm dropping an answer for teh loz